# Can some tell me why the A also changed?

Tags: java

Returns a list consisting of the elements of A followed by the elements of B. May NOT modify items of A.  Use 'new'. The `IntList` looks like this.

```
public class IntList { 
    public int first;
    public IntList rest;

    public IntList(int first, IntList rest) {
        this.first = first;
        this.rest = rest;
    }
}

public static IntList catenate(IntList A, IntList B) {
    //TODO:  fill in method
    IntList C = new IntList(A.first, A.rest);
    IntList L = C;
    while(L.rest != null) {
        L = L.rest;
    }
    L.rest = B;
    return C;
}
```

I dont know why in the end of it, the A also change to C.
Below is the test.

```
public void testCatenate() {
    IntList A = IntList.list(1, 2, 3);
    IntList B = IntList.list(4, 5, 6);
    IntList exp = IntList.list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    assertEquals(exp, IntList.catenate(A, B));
    assertEquals(IntList.list(1, 2, 3), A);
}
```

And the result is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :(1, 2, 3)
Actual   :(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: What is `IntList`? And `IntList L = C;` is **not** a *copy*.

Comment: sorry for that, already change it.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor, the line

```
this.rest = rest;
```

makes `rest` in the new list reference the exact same list as was passed in.  This means that after the first line of `catenate`, `C.rest` and `A.rest` are references to the exact same list.

Then, the loop involving `L` and the subsequent `L.rest = B;` concatenates `B` to the end of `C.rest`.  But since this is the same list as `A.rest`, it appears that `B` has been concatenated to both `A` and `C`.

To fix this, get rid of `this.rest = rest;` in the constructor, and replace it with code that actually copies the entries in `rest`.

Comment: The constructor is fine, the problem is the `catenate` method modifies the list A, instead of making a copy.  The fields in `IntList` should also be final.

Comment: The constructor is NOT fine. This is an attempt at implementing a linked list of int. It doesn't make sense for two linked lists to share most of their nodes, but not the head node.

Comment: It makes plenty of sense to share all the nodes except the head.  This way you for example avoid copying the whole list when all you want to change is the head. This concept is called structural sharing and is very common.  Based on this definition it's almost certainly what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an IntList to be modified, make the fields first and rest final so that they can't be changed once set.

The catenate method needs to make a copy of A, so it doesn't modify the original list.

To do this, loop though the list as you are doing, but at each step save the value (either in another IntList or in another structure like an ArrayList.  Then once you get the last value, create a new IntList, with first as the last value in A, and rest as B.

```
new IntList(L.first, B);
```

Now loop through the items you saved from A, in reverse order adding them onto this new List.